# Ignore a certain tag in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE editor in my project and I would like to make it ignore the tag <--image-->.

Now, if I write this tag, it replaces it with `<p>&nbsp;</p>`

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to add this tag to your valid tinymce tags.
Have acloser look at the tinymce paramter valid_elements and valid_children.